# How to verify if Redirect from API is working

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-webapi, http-redirect, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an API method that needs to redirect to URL based on some input provided.

```
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult GetUrl(string input)
    {
        // retrieve a url based on the input
        string url = GetUrl(input);
        return Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

When I debug this method using postman, I see that the correct URL is retrieved and the call to Redirect is made. However, in the postman, I am getting an HTTP 404 status. My questions:

1. How can I get some appropriate Redirect HTTP status code?
2. From postman, is there any way to verify if the redirect to URL was performed?

Comment: Do you want to redirect to an external URL, or some URL on the same host?

Comment: Redirect to an external URL

Comment: I'll answer, I think I found your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm thinking your URL that you're passing does not include `http://` or `https://` in front of it, and ASP.NET is trying to redirect you to http://example.com/url instead of redirecting to an external site. Try adding `https://` or `http://` in front of your URL that you pass to your `GetUrl` method. You should then get a `200 OK` in Postman.

Example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetUrl([FromQuery]string url)
        {
            return Redirect("https://" + url);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, if you pass `url=google.com` to the application, you'll get redirected to https://google.com/ and get a `200 OK` in Postman.